# Scattered plot changes with numpy polyfit

Tags: python, numpy

i want to know the angle of a polyline, therefore i'm using numpy polyfit.

if i scatter the list, i get what i expect.

if i print the polyfit, the scatter changes, and i'm not getting what i expect, i don't know what to do.

x = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

y = a list which is updated every hour. Running it while typing this message, gives me:

y = [30243.73, 30408.42, 30620.55, 30819.66, 31042.16, 31215.93]

```
#z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

gives me this, which is right:
[image]

But if i want to add the polyfit, In this case i expect a straight line going from the left bottom corner to the right one above. Instead i get this:

```
 z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(z, linewidth=2.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried several degrees so far... (why do the scattered points move?)

Comment: The scatter plot didn't move. the plot is shown to fit z in to the plot

Answer (score 0):

You are using polyfit wrongly that polyfit gives you is the `m` and `c` in `y = m * x + c`

This is the correct way to use it

```
[m, c] = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
z = m * x + c
plt.plot(x, z)
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why m, is such a 'weird' value now that i use a static and made up x list? Normally the list x is also updated every hour, and gives me this regression coefficient. If i calculate it now, with both actual lists, it gives -0.09, but as shown it gives -230 ?

Comment: I got no idea what you mean. But polyfit coefficients are supposed to be dynamic to fit ur set of points. Since the set of points changes u should expect m and c to change accordingly. They are not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want is the fitting result of `np.polyfit()`. `np.polyfit` returns the coefficients of a polynomial regression. You can use `np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,1)(x)` to get your results.

```
z = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,1))(x)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(z, linewidth=2.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you exactly what i needed. Now i can check what's going on while trying to calculate the angle.